# How can I create an object which masks and cuts into other objects?

Tags: masking

I'm looking to create a object that masks and cut into other objects. So far this is what I have.

[image: [So far this is what I have.]] The second object in that image needs to be transparent and will take a chunk out the first cube.

To give you a idea on what I'm doing the second object will have location keyframes and will slowly eat away at the first cube.

I'm finding it hard to put this into words so I've made a image to try and show you. This is what it should look like, rendered. [image: this is what I would like]

This is what it would look like if you saw the wire frames of all the objects.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how the Boolean modifier works set to Difference and the target set to viewport display wireframe.

Comment: I've just used this but it only works once when you click apply. I'm looking for exactly what you said but in a way where a location key-frame could eat away at a object.

Comment: not true: create the boolean modifier, then select the second cube and hide it. You don't need to apply it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Result]

Add a *Boolean* modifier to the cube you want to remove parts from. Set the operation to *Difference* and select an object that is used as volume to calculate the difference.
Then enable the *Restriction Toggle* for *Disable in Renders* (camera icon) for the same object that is used in the *Boolean* modifier for the *Difference* operation. This will hide it in the render. You can also hide it in the viewport in case you want to see the effect of the modifier right away as shown in the video at the beginning.

Once this is configured you can animate the objects. The cube will have parts removed without the other object being visible in the render.

[image: 3D View with Boolean modifier]

[image: Restriction toggle]

[image: Disable in Render]